# Why do I have to enable isapi v4.0.30319 when I add web.config transforms to VB .NET site?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, iis-7.5

I have a VB MVC 3 site that I am making changes to. It has always been worked on in VS2010. Before the changes, it works just fine in IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard with ASP.NET ISAPI 2.0.50727 allowed and ASP.NET ISAPI 4.0.30319 not allowed.

The changes I made:
-moved connection strings to web.config
-added a solution configuration. Now I have Debug, Release, Release (Backup)
-added config transforms
-added markup in each transform file to transform connection strings

The first time I did this, I opened the site in VS2012 by mistake and it converted some things. I wish I had read the window with the changes. I did the changes and put the site back up. It would only work when I allowed 4.0.30319.

I reverted to a previous version of the site before the VS2012 conversion and to make sure, I put it back up on the server and it worked fine with 4.0.30319 not allowed

I made the changes again, and again, the site will only work when I enable 4.0.30319

I don't know anything about ISAPIs. I'm not in charge of the servers and I don't want to change setting I don't understand.

**My questions:**

Why do I have to enable 4.0.30319?

Can I do my changes without enabling 4.0.30319?

What caused the need for allowing 4.0.30319? In other words, how can I avoid this from happening again?